# Change python loop to start from parent folder

Tags: python

I have the a loop I am using and it works great. It appears like:

```
# Import OVITO modules.
from ovito.io import *
from ovito.modifiers import *

# Import NumPy module.
import numpy
import sys

for i in range(1,25):

    with open("{}.out".format(i),'w') as f:
        for j in range(1,401):

                node = import_file("../Angle{}/{}eV/cascade.dump".format(i,j),multiple_frames = True)
                ovito.dataset.anim.current_frame = 11

                mod = WignerSeitzAnalysisModifier(per_type_occupancies = True)
                mod.reference.load("../../../../STP/position_perfect_300.dump")
                node.modifiers.append(mod)
                node.compute()
                node.modifiers.append(SelectExpressionModifier(expression = 'ParticleType==2 && Occupancy.1==0 && Occupancy.2==0'))
                node.compute()

                f.write("%i\n" % numpy.count_nonzero(node.output.particle_properties['Selection']))
f.close()
```

Is there any way to edit this loop so that instead of looking for i in range(1,25) in current directory, it looks for it in parent directory? This would help me clean up my files a lot. Any ideas?

Comment: What about `with open("../{}.out".format(i),'w') as f:`?